# "...what you've put together here" : What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

What does this sentence mean?

> They would likely be interested in what you've put together here!

When I should use this?

Comment: It isn't a complete sentence, so it's hard to say exactly what it means.  Can you give us more context?  Where did you see this?

Comment: "They would likely be interested in what you've put together here!"

Comment: 'Put together' means 'to construct or create' as in 'put together a new bookcase'. Your sentence probably means, "I think the chances that they like what you've created here are rather high".

Comment: Using "here" at the end of the sentence is common in American English. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162234/what-is-the-meaning-of-here-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: Likely is often used instead of probably in American English. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311266/will-likely-vs-will-probably-in-ameng-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What you've put together here":

- something ("what")
- either nearby or currently the topic of conversation ("here")
- that the addressee has assembled ("you have put together")

The phrasal verb "[put
together](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_together#Verb)" is used more often
than its synonyms when the object is something written—e.g., research, a report,
or a proposal.  So a speaker describing such items would be more likely to use
this phrase than another.  "Put together" also implies that the assembly
required effort or creativity.

Example:

> You make a list of interesting questions on ell.stackexchange.com and show it
>   to me.  I know a friend who could use it.  The list is a thing, we are already
>   talking about it, and you assembled it.  Further, the list is the written
>   outcome of research, and it took effort.  Therefore, I could say, "They would
>   likely be interested in what you've put together here!"

Example:

> You and I work at a company.  You write a contract that will reduce what a
>   customer pays but keep our profit the same, and you e-mail it to me.  The
>   contract is a thing, it is the topic of conversation when I reply, and you
>   constructed it.  Additionally, the contract is a written proposal, and it took
>   creativity.  Therefore, I could say, "They would likely be interested in what
>   you've put together here!"

Example:

> You and I are filling candy bowls.  You mix chocolates and hard candies
>   together in a bowl, and I know a friend who likes that combination.  The mix
>   is a thing, it is nearby, and you created it.  But it is not something
>   written, nor did you need much effort or creativity to make it.  I could say,
>   "They would likely be interested in what you've put together here!", and I
>   would be understood.  But the word choice would be poor, unless I say it
>   jokingly, acting like you are clever for inventing the combination.

Comment: Someone said that to me. I think you are correct. Thank you